# Difference between Return and Break in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, return, break

Want to know the difference between Return and break in using them while writing a SQL Server stored procedure.

Thanks

Comment: [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181271.aspx) the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998(v=sql.90).aspx) did you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Break` terminates a loop or other control statement.
`Return` sends a value back to the invoker.

You can technically break out of a control statement with a `Return`, but this is a very poor practice.